# Declare a Swift protocol which has a property return value CollectionType<Int>?

Tags: swift, protocols

Is something like

```
protocol A {
    var intCollection: CollectionType<Int> { get }
}
```

or

```
protocol A {
    typealias T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == Int
    var intCollection: T
}
```

possible in Swift 2.1?

---

**Update for Swift 4**

Swift 4 now support this feature! [read more in here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/using-generic-type-constraints-in-swift-4)

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as a nested protocol, but it's fairly straightforward using the type erasers (the "Any" structs).

```
protocol A {
    var intCollection: AnyRandomAccessCollection<Int> { get }
}
```

This is actually often quite convenient for return values because the caller usually doesn't care so much about the actual type. You just have to throw a `return AnyRandomAccessCollection(resultArray)` at the end of your function and it all just works. Lots of stdlib now returns `Any` erasers. For the return value problem, it's almost always the way I recommend. It has the nice side effect of making `A` concrete, so it's much easier to work with.

If you want to keep the `CollectionType`, then you need to restrict it at the point that you create a function that needs it. For example:

```
protocol A {
    typealias IntCollection: CollectionType
    var intCollection: IntCollection { get }
}

extension A where IntCollection.Generator.Element == Int {
    func sum() -> Int {
        return intCollection.reduce(0, combine: +)
    }
}
```

This isn't ideal, since it means you can have `A` with the wrong kind of collection type. They just won't have a `sum` method. You also will find yourself repeating that "where IntCollection.Generator.Element == Int" in a surprising number of places.

In my experience, it is seldom worth this effort, and you quickly come back to Arrays (which are the dominant CollectionType anyway). But when you need it, these are the two major approaches. That's the best we have today.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this upright as in your question, and there exists several thread here on SO on the subject of using protocols as type definitions, with content that itself contains Self or associated type requirements (result: this is not allowed). See e.g. the [link provided by Christik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type), or thread [Error using associated types and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070873/error-using-associated-types-and-generics).

Now, for you example above, you could do the following workaround, however, perhaps mimicing the behaviour you're looking for

```
protocol A {
    typealias MyCollectionType
    typealias MyElementType
    func getMyCollection() -> MyCollectionType
    func printMyCollectionType()
    func largestValue() -> MyElementType?
}

struct B<U: Comparable, T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == U>: A {
    typealias MyCollectionType = T
    typealias MyElementType = U
    var myCollection : MyCollectionType

    init(coll: MyCollectionType) {
        myCollection = coll
    }

    func getMyCollection() -> MyCollectionType {
        return myCollection
    }

    func printMyCollectionType() {
        print(myCollection.dynamicType)
    }

    func largestValue() -> MyElementType? {
        guard var largestSoFar = myCollection.first else {
            return nil
        }
        for item in myCollection {
            if item > largestSoFar {
                largestSoFar = item
            }
        }
        return largestSoFar
    }
}
```

So you can implement blueprints for your generic collection types in you protocol `A`, and implement these blueprints in the *"interface type"* `B`, which also contain the actual collection as a member property. I have taken the `largestValue()` method above [from here](http://austinzheng.com/2015/09/29/swift-generics-pt-2/).

Example usage:

```
/* Examples */
var myArr = B<Int, Array<Int>>(coll: [1, 2, 3])
var mySet = B<Int, Set<Int>>(coll: [10, 20, 30])
var myRange = B<Int, Range<Int>>(coll: 5...10)
var myStrArr = B<String, Array<String>>(coll: ["a", "c", "b"])

myArr.printMyCollectionType()    // Array<Int>
mySet.printMyCollectionType()    // Set<Int>
myRange.printMyCollectionType()  // Range<Int>
myStrArr.printMyCollectionType() // Array<String>

/* generic T type constrained to protocol 'A' */
func printLargestValue<T: A>(coll: T) {
    print(coll.largestValue() ?? "Empty collection")
}

printLargestValue(myArr)    // 3
printLargestValue(mySet)    // 30
printLargestValue(myRange)  // 10
printLargestValue(myStrArr) // c
```

Comment: I read some of the questions and answers, the workarounds are not fancy.

Comment: Coming from an OOP background myself, I've learned (the hard way...) in Swift that when things starts to become messy, maybe my approach to the original problem should be re-considered: protocol oriented programming (POP) is, with all similarities to OOP, still quite different, and I believe that the Swift authors had this in mind when writing the language. So: if you think things start to go messy, my advice is to return to the origin an try to find an alternative approach to the problem or task at hand.